# Developer Tools Keeps Popping Up

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools

I have clean installed Chrome twice now but the problem persists.

The Developer Toool opens up when i navigate any website. This is random. I close it and it opens again.

I am on Chrome latest version (Version 44.0.2403.107 m)

There are various thread on Google but no definite solution yet.

An indicative image of the issue is in Right Hand Side

[image]